# My Nopcommerce plugin call a Nop.web's Language selector Action instead of Nop.Admin

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce and I had make a plugin, now in my plugin i found that on admin panel my plugin page all thing are load form `nop.admin` but Language selector of common controller is called form `nop.admin`, why?

Rest of admin panel page are load properly just my plugin takes `nop.web` common controllers language selector method but i want `nop.admin` controller's.

Is am I miss some thing?
can any one suggest me how can i call nop.admin's action.